If magnetic field is frame dependent then why the em wave is frame independent
"In special relativity, magnetic fields are frame-dependent quantities that transform between reference frames, changing their magnitude and direction based on the relative motion of observers. In contrast, electromagnetic waves appear to have a universal, frame-independent speed of propagation and characteristics. What fundamental principles of electromagnetism and special relativity explain this apparent paradox - why are magnetic fields frame-dependent while electromagnetic waves maintain a consistent nature across different inertial reference frames?"

EM waves are frame dependent. Take a plane wave and transform it (parallel to $\vec k$). You will find that $|\vec k|$ and $\omega$ transform according to the relativistic Doppler shift.
Nevertheless, the dispersion relation will satisfy:
$$ \frac{\omega} k = \frac{\omega'}{k'} = c $$
in both frames (so the phase velocity remains $c$).
Of course $E^2-c^2B^2$ and $\vec E \cdot \vec B$ are Lorentz scalar.
The field strengths will be different.
What won't be different is the phase:
$$ \phi(x, t) = \vec k \cdot \vec x -\omega t = -k_{\mu}x^{\mu}$$
That's a manifest Lorentz scalar.
The number of photons in a fixed region of spacetime will also be constant.
I'll leave polarization as an exercise.
